# How to prevent ARSCNView from rotating

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, sceneview

I have a class as below

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, SCNPhysicsContactDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
```

How to prevent the sceneView from rotating?

I tried many ways such as

add

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
           return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
       }
     
       override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
           return false
       }
```

in UIViewController

Or add

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask
    {
       
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    }
```

in App delegate

Or set
[image]

Or set
[image]
all don't work.

When I run it on my ipad, it always rotates when I change my ipad orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent rotation in all your code, you can try: go in the info.plist, go to "Supported interface orientation (iPad)" or "Supported interface orientation (iPhone)", open a section up with the disclosure triangle and delete the items you don't want to rotate to for the iPad/iPhone.

Comment: I did that, but it doesn't work

Comment: The last line in your info plist screenshot, did you change it? Because it doesn’t show